# Updating WP7 ListBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, listboxitem

I have a webservice which contains a phone numbers.
The phone queries the webservice to get the phones list and display them in a ListBox.
The problem is that I do not know how to query the phone contacts database for every phone, get the contact name for it and show the name instead of the phone in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows Phone SDK 7.1 gives you read-only access to the user’s contact data, aggregated across the user's different accounts. For more information, see [Contacts and Calendar for Windows Phone.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202972%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

[This MSDN article should get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286414%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

And this should help too:

```
Contacts cont = new Contacts();
cont.SearchCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        foreach (var contact in e.Results)
        {
            string name = contact.DisplayName;
        }
    };
cont.SearchAsync("07000000000", FilterKind.PhoneNumber, null);
```

Comment: Hi, I know how to search the contacts and get the name for a number, but how to add all the results to the ListBox. For example I have 5 numbers to search for, for every number I want to get the names from the contacts and show the name in the listbox

Comment: Perhaps you can build a list of names in the SearchCompleted callback and set that as the ItemsSource on your ListBox.